# Creating a C++ Qt Gui for a Python logic

Tags: python, c++, qt, user-interface

I was presented with a Python logic for which I need to create a GUI. I want to use Qt for that purpose and ideally I would like to program it in C++, without using the Qt Creator.

What are recommended ways of combining a C++ Qt GUI and a Python logic, perhaps with a controlling layer which is either in Python or C++?

Due to prior research, I'm aware of certain tools like PySide, PythonQt, SWIG, Shiboken and others (although I haven't used them so far) and that it is very simple to import *.ui files into Python, but the number of possible ways is a bit overwhelming and I could not come up with a "good solution" so far.

Ideally, I would *not* use Qt Designer, but create the GUI (windows, custom widgets, helper classes etc) by hand, combine them into one or few classes which I expose to a Python/C++ controlling layer (by wrappers? DLL?) which manages the communication between GUI and logic.

How can I achieve this?

A short version of this question might just be: How can I use a Qt C++ GUI with a Python logic?

Comment: Why not using a [native python GUI framework](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+gui+programming&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&oq=python+gui&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l4.10154j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) instead of Qt?

Comment: Frankly, because I know Qt...

Comment: Frankly, knowing a tool doesn't make it the best solution for a given problem (e.g. _The golden hammer_ or _Silver Bullet_ Anti-Pattern).

Comment: If you do decide to stick with python and still want to use Qt, I would recommend PySide2, which is now officially part of Qt

Comment: @LCsa If you know Qt and assuming that you have written the logic part of your application then it is best to use some Qt binding such as PyQt5 or PySide2 because you already know the python syntax and Qt methods.

Comment: It's about the technical solution to the problem of wanting to combine a Python logic to a C++ Qt GUI. The question of that being a good idea or not, is, although justified, a different one. 

@Felix and eyllanesc: Yeah, it seems using Qt from the Python side would be the least cumbersome way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your GUI application using qt c++ and wrap controler logic written in a python api embedding the python api.
https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html
But if you have many methods that will be boring to do and you may have some memory leaks if not well written in th c++ side.

Another solution may be using rpc calls to a python api using a webservice (rest api/json rpc ....Etc...). Qt application is client of a python rest api. 
like this you split the c code from the python one. You can do that using json rpc calls , or other apis,like jcon (https://github.com/joncol/jcon-cpp).
You will too be able to find python and QT xml rpc api able to talk together.

swig (http://swig.org) may have some capability , but it is better used in the other way : calling c func from python

Comment: _Swig_ is the next _silver bullet_ so?

Comment: Thanks, I already saw coming that it'd be possible to create an interface, but it would be very cumbersome...