# How to combine Python logic and Qt C++ GUI

Tags: python, c++, qt, user-interface, pyside

I was presented with a Python logic and a GUI written in C++ Qt and asked to combine them. Before I choose the route of re-implementing the GUI in e.g. PySide, I would like to know which way would be the smoothest to achieve such a combination. Would I rather make the C++ GUI available to the Python logic (and a controlling layer) or the other way around?

I will gladly provide more information, if necessary. My problem is a lack of experience in that matter and that there are so many solutions of how to make code of one language accessible to the other, that I feel a bit smothered in options.

In this case, the Python logic is actually just a (too large, but that's another topic) class which provides some signal processing methods.

---

This is a crisp rephrasing of a prior [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54387038/creating-a-c-qt-gui-for-a-python-logic?noredirect=1#comment95587820_54387038), which I somewhat clumsily posed, and therefore missed its aim.

Comment: If you ask for tutorial of PySide2 or PyQt5 then that is clearly not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: It is clearly not a tutorial question. It's a question about which tools would help me to achieve what I was asked for, from which side I should tackle it (C++ side or Python side) and what the major concept of the solution could look like (i.e. create bindings for the gui to use it in Python! _or_ Create bindings for the logic to use it in C++   etc...)

Comment: So something even more wide and deep than tutorial? A book? That is not improving the situation.

Comment: It depends a bit on what your _Python logic_ actually is. Is it ready console application? Is it a function to call? You could start the python program as sub-process out of your Qt GUI. You could also embed a Python interpreter to run your python code inside your C++ application. May be, try to describe a little bit closer what your _Python logic_ actually does and how it is called. (I ignored the option to just re-implement the Python code in C++.)

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for trying to help. I edited in a small explanation. The python logic is actually just a very limited number of classes providing data processing methods. Along the lines of "reading in data", "perform a FFT", "calculateXyzStuff" etc; nothing too complicated.

Comment: We use Python as "macro" language in our interactive C++/OpenGL/Qt-GUI visual simulation application. There were some pitfalls but finally it works not bad. We embedded the Python interpreter in our C++ application. We added some capsule objects to Python to be able to modify C++ objects out of Python scripts. For this, we didn't use any interface tool but wrote anything in C/C++ based on the Python doc. [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/index.html) (and some google searches for detail issues).

Comment: @Scheff Thank you, I'll look into that part of the documentation!